# Есть ли возможность при создании BufferedReader вместо System.in вписать какие-либо значения?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

Есть ли возможность при использовании

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

вместо `System.in` вписать значения, например, как

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Source: "1 2 3 4 5").
```

Мне приходится много раз запускать код для проверки и очень сильно утомляет каждый раз вводить с клавиатуры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, разумеется, можно создать экземпляр класса [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) класс и обернуть его в `BufferedReader`:

```java
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("1 2 3 4 5 6"))) {
    // ... используйте буферизированное чтение
}
```

или передавать `Reader` как параметр в некоторый метод, в котором уже будет использоваться буферизованное чтение:

```java
public static void readSomething(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        // ... основной функционал
    }
}

readSomething(new StringReader("aa bb cc dd"));
```